# How to run python file in google-colaboratory with comand line arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, drive

I have a python 3.8 file that runs with four arguments as follows.

`python test.py INPUT_FILE_1 INPUT_FILE_2 OUTPUT_FILE_1 OUTPUT_FILE_2`

is there a way to run similar command, while using the file from google drive?

Answer (score 0):

Try running :

```
!python test.py INPUT_FILE_1 INPUT_FILE_2 OUTPUT_FILE_1 OUTPUT_FILE_2
```

or

```
!python3 test.py INPUT_FILE_1 INPUT_FILE_2 OUTPUT_FILE_1 OUTPUT_FILE_2
```

or

```
%run test.py INPUT_FILE_1 INPUT_FILE_2 OUTPUT_FILE_1 OUTPUT_FILE_2
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a Python file in Colab is really simple

## Explanation

In your Code Editor,

```
!
```

Entering a Examination Mark means you are accessing your terminal here,

## Other things

So, to run a file, or any command from terminal like `ls` or `cd` or `dir` or `pip`, just type `!` before it,

To Change your Directory add a *Percentage Sign* before it like `%cd /content/My_Repo/`

## Steps

To run a Python 3.x file type

`!python3 your_file.py <options_if_any>`

or

`!python3 my_file.py`

Hope, this clears it for you ;)